# JavaScript function not working on PHP page

Tags: php, javascript

Consider:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<!-- js start -->
    <script src="<?=base_url();?>js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?=base_url();?>js/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?=base_url();?>js/aspectza.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- js end -->

<!-- BEGIN: load jquery plugins -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js">
<!-- END: load jquery plugins -->

<!--
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url();?>css/validationEngine.jquery.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="<?=base_url();?>js/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?=base_url();?>js/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
-->

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

    function printSelect()
    {
        if (document.getElementById != null)
        {
            var html = '<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n';

            if (document.getElementsByTagName != null)
            {
                var headTags = document.getElementsByTagName("head");
                if (headTags.length > 0)
                html += headTags[0].innerHTML;
            }

            html += '\n</HE' + 'AD>\n<BODY>\n';

            html += '\n<TABLE>\n';

            var printSelect = document.getElementById("printSelect");

            if (printSelect != null)
            {
                html += printSelect.innerHTML;
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Could not find the printReady section in the HTML");
                return;
            }
            html += '\n</TA' + 'BLE>\n</FO' + 'RM>';
            html += '\n</BO' + 'DY>\n</HT' + 'ML>';

            var printWin = window.open("", "printForm");
            printWin.document.open();
            printWin.document.write(html);
            printWin.document.close();
            printWin.print();
            printWin.close();
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Sorry, the print ready feature is only available in modern browsers.");
        }
    }
</script>

<form name="summary" OnSubmit="return printSelect();">

    <input type="image" src="icon.jpg"" name="print">

    printSelect() function not found!!!
```

[image]

Comment: The html is invalid in the code you posted: misses head and body tag, and the form is not closed. Also, try with a "submit" button first

Comment: View the source of the actual page, and show that too. The javascript doesn't execute until after the PHP is done, so knowing the intermediary step is useful.

Comment: Are you loading two versions of jQuery.js (1.5.1 and latest)? And do you really expect anybody to be using a browser so old that it doesn't support `document.getElementById`?

Comment: silly html code! follow the standards

Comment: The HTML is also incorrect near "`src="icon.jpg"" name="print">`".

Answer (score 0):

The script tag is not closed.

Close the script tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<!-- js start-->
    <script src="<?=base_url();?>js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?=base_url();?>js/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?=base_url();?>js/aspectza.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- js end-->

  <!-- BEGIN: load jquery plugins -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js"></script>
  <!-- END: load jquery plugins -->

    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
        function printSelect()
        {
            if (document.getElementById !=null)
            {
                var html='<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n';

                if (document.getElementsByTagName != null)
                {
                    var headTags = document.getElementsByTagName("head");
                    if (headTags.length > 0)
                    html += headTags[0].innerHTML;
                }

                html += '\n</HE' + 'AD>\n<BODY>\n';

                html+='\n<TABLE>\n';

                var printSelect = document.getElementById("printSelect");

                if (printSelect != null)
                {
                    html += printSelect.innerHTML;
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Could not find the printReady section in the HTML");
                    return;
                }
                html+= '\n</TA' + 'BLE>\n</FO' + 'RM>';
                html += '\n</BO' + 'DY>\n</HT' + 'ML>';

                var printWin = window.open("","printForm");
                printWin.document.open();
                printWin.document.write(html);
                printWin.document.close();
                printWin.print();
                printWin.close();
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Sorry, the print ready feature is only available in modern browsers.");
            }
        }
    </script>

    <form name="summary" OnSubmit="return printSelect();">

        <input type="image" src="icon.jpg""  name="print">
```

Comment: but i need those script files to do my jquery functions

Answer (score 0):

Do as in [Pradeep Singh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982736/javascript-function-not-working-on-php-page/8982820#8982820). Plus.

I guess you are using CodeIgniter?

If yes, make sure you have loaded the "url" helper.

Another step you can do is, view the source of the file, and check every link of your JavaScript.

Check your $config['base_url']. There should be a slash at the end.